# HTML Email - button has no padding on outlook

Tags: html, email, button, html-email

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible to do the border with the same padding as the button above. The solution might seem like it is when I add the border to the td but I can not do that because in other client the border has border-radius which is not visible here. Any ideas? Thanks

code for the second button:

```html
<!-- BUTTON -->
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid" 
    role="presentation" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0 0 40px 0;" 
            valign="top">
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                class="main-button-mob-width" role="presentation"
                    style="max-width: 80%; min-width: auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
                        class="out-main-button-padding" 
                        style="border-radius: 50px; padding: 0; font-family: 
                        'Arial Black', Gadget, Arial, 
                        Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; 
                        line-height: 22px; mso-text-raise: 4px;"
                        valign="top">
                        <a class="out-main-button-a"
                            href="#" style="display: block; 
                            border-radius: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; 
                            border: 3px solid #061539; 
                            mso-border-alt: 8px solid #061539; 
                            padding: 15px 35px 15px 35px; mso-padding-alt: 4px; 
                            color: #061539; text-decoration: none;"
                            target="_blank" title="">
                            <span style="color: #061539; text-decoration: none; 
                                background-color: #ffffff">INVITA A TUS AMIGOS
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- BUTTON end -->
```

Comment: Your title is about the padding but your question is about the border. The differences are clear, but it is hard to understand what the problem is. There is `border-radius: 50px;` on the `a`. If you remove that, they are more similar.

Comment: Well I ment there is no padding so the border does not look the same. It is obvious because the “a” is inline element but the border-raius does not work anywhere else. The border has to be there and also the border-radius. The only thing is than in outlook the border radius is not visible but in other clients it is.. I just need the button to be the same width/ height with the border around..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Outlook you cannot change an inline element such as `<a>` to a block element (`display:block`). So it ignores padding, margins and such because these are block element styles.

Therefore, for cross-email compatibility, you either need to put padding on the `<td>` (which doesn't extend the clickable part, but only makes it *look* like the button is bigger, or, you can apply a hack as described by Mark Robbins.

Solution 1: (Easiest) TD button

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" 
    class="out-main-button-padding" 
    style="border-radius: 50px; padding: 15px 35px 15px 35px;
    border-radius: 50px; background-color: #ffffff; 
    border: 3px solid #061539; 
    mso-border-alt: 8px solid #061539; 
    mso-padding-alt: 4px;  font-family: 
    NIVEaBrandType-Bold, 'Arial Black', Gadget, Arial, 
    Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 22px; mso-text-raise: 4px;"
    valign="top">
    <a class="out-main-button-a"
        href="https://nivea.com" style="display: block; 
        color: #061539; text-decoration: none;"
        target="_blank" title="">
        <span style="color: #061539; text-decoration: none; 
            background-color: #ffffff">INVITA A TUS AMIGOS
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

All I've done is move the block-level styles from the `<a>` to the `<td>`. You can still leave the `display:block` on the `<a>` to make the clickable area bigger for those email clients that support this.

Solution 2: Mark Robbin's A button

```
<a href="https://example.com/" style="background: #333; border: 2px solid #f00; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; color: #fff; border-radius: 4px; display:inline-block; mso-padding-alt:0;text-underline-color:#333"><!--[if mso]><i style="letter-spacing: 25px;mso-font-width:-100%;mso-text-raise:30pt" hidden>&nbsp;</i><![endif]--><span style="mso-text-raise:15pt;">Link Text</span><!--[if mso]><i style="letter-spacing: 25px;mso-font-width:-100%" hidden>&nbsp;</i><![endif]-->
</a>
```

Change the left and right padding by changing the `letter-spacing` value (on the left and right of the link text).

Change the bottom padding by changing the `mso-text-raise` value in the `<span>`.

Change the top padding by changing the `mso-text-raise` value in the `<i>`.

(Detailed explanation on https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/link-button)

Comment: By the way, adding border-radius in Outlook is possible, but you have to use VML. See a complete writeup here https://www.litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design/

Comment: Thank you so much!! The second solution solved my problem! The only problem with the first one was that the border radius didn't work anywhere but I need to have it anywhere where the clients supports it, where not it is ok to be without it :) But I will look on the VML you are talking about, thank you!